# How to send password String in rest call in REST Api in Spring?

Tags: spring, rest, api, passwords

Hi!

I have made a basic user authentication with Spring Boot's Spring Security.
I am adding some default users at the start of the application, but I also have to implement a way of creating a new user at runtime. So, I want to create a new RestControler call to add a new user to Spring Security.

To be clear, I think I have everyting figured out, except for the part when I actally send request paramaters in a call.

**So, my question is:**

**What is the best/safest way to send password in a rest api call, when creating a new user?**

I guess using a `@PathVariable` is not very safe, as the url calls can be intercepted easily:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "add/{login}/{password}", method = PUT)
public User add(@PathVariable("login") String login,
                @PathVariable("password") String password) {

    return us.addUser(login, password);
}
```

The same for `@RequestParam`:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "add", method = PUT)
public User add(@RequestParam(value = "login") String login,
                @RequestParam(value = "password") String password) {

    return us.addUser(login, password);
}
```

Maybe sending them in headers?

Anyhow, this is the first time I do something like this and could really use an advice on what is the common practice in this situations. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should use the `POST` method instead of `PUT`, because `PUT` is an idempotent method.

The safest way to send password is using `@RequestBody`. You can use the method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "add", method = POST)
public User add(@RequestBody User user) {

    return us.addUser(user);
}
```

The request will look something like this:

```
{"username" : "user", "password" : "encoded_password"}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out. Also, I will keep in mind what you said about POST and PUT. Cheers!